# How to display image in a Wordpress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need the loop to show my post's attached image that i linked thru URLs and so on..

How do i implement it to my wordpress?

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
</div>
```

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: yea.. the function in Add media "Insert from URL"

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
```

**using this you can show all attachment of a post.**

**`$post->ID` is id of the post, Use this in your Current loop.**

Other functions which you might find helpful ..

**1. [Wp Get Attachment Image Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)**

**2.  [Wp Get Attachment  Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link)**

Comment: appreciate your help. however, it appear the "featured image" which i dont actually want, tried every single option u suggested, but it doesn't work quite well. my blog  [link](http://four6ixteen.com/blog/) still doesnt show linked URL